Eliminate all special characters without using stored procedure and functions
This is my sample text in data
this is ! Alex23 & and % doing/ *SQL2019

and I want this output
this is Alex23 and doing SQL2019

In my organization we are not allowed to use stored procedures or functions. Currently we are using these statements to do this:
update tablename set columnname = replace(columnname, '!', '')
update tablename set columnname = replace(columnname, '@', '')
update tablename set columnname = replace(columnname, '#', '')
update tablename set columnname = replace(columnname, '$', '')
update tablename set columnname = replace(columnname, '%', '')
update tablename set columnname = replace(columnname, '&', '')

Is there a better way?

You can nest multiple replace statements in a single update

Use TRANSLATE to replace multiple characters at once.

The special characters you have mentioned in your question are not all that exist. So do you really need to remove all special characters or only some of them (those you have shown in the question)? And if you notice you don't want such characters in this column, don't you think you should create a check constraint to prevent them?

You seem to want to collapse spaces around the eliminated characters. What are all the rules around this whole operation?

I guess something like https://dbfiddle.uk/2m3ug7Hm should do, but the question is not really clear yet.

What is your SQL Server version?

A typical way or removing a known set of characters is to use a combination of TRANSLATE() and REPLACE() to first map the unallowed characters all to a single unallowed character and then eliminate all occurrences of that character.
REPLACE(TRANSLATE(string, 'aeiou', REPLICATE('a', LEN('aeiou'))), 'a', '')

However, if we are starting with a list of characters to keep, we first need to convert that to a list of characters to remove. I can think of two ways of doing this:

Generate the entire character set and subtract out the characters to keep. This is feasible for VARCHAR but not for NVARCHAR.
Remove the keeper characters from the source string and use that intermediate result as the characters to remove in a second operation.

The following demonstrates the second technique:
DECLARE @allowed NVARCHAR(100) =
    N'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    + N'0123456789'
    + ' '

SELECT T.*, C.cleaned
FROM tablename T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT REPLACE(TRANSLATE(T.columnname
               , @allowed, REPLICATE('A', LEN(@allowed + 'x') - 1))
               , 'A', '')
               AS unallowed
) U
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT REPLACE(TRANSLATE(T.columnname
               , U.unallowed, REPLICATE('@', LEN(U.unallowed + 'x') - 1))
               , '@', '')
               AS cleaned
) C

I used fixed characters "A" and "@" in the above. If the allowed/unallowed strings are not known in advance, you could instead use LEFT(@allowed, 1) and LEFT(U.unallowed, 1).
The LEN(string +'x') - 1 is needed because LEN() does not count trailing spaces. The REPLICATE() function is used to generate a translate-to string the same length as the translate-from string. Conveniently, the TRANSLATE() function does not complain about duplicates in the translate-from string.
See this question for techniques on how to eliminate repeating spaces from the final string. An adaptation of the top answer follows:
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(C.cleaned,
               ' ', ' @'), '@ ', ''), ' @', ' ')
               AS dedupedspaces
) D

You might also wish to add a TRIM() to the above, if you need to eliminate any leading and trailing spaces.
Results (with some extra test data):



columnname
cleaned
dedupedspaces




this is ! Alex23 & and % doing/ *SQL2019
this is  Alex23  and  doing SQL2019
this is Alex23 and doing SQL2019


ABC 123
ABC 123
ABC 123


@#$%




a←b↑c→d↓e
abcde
abcde


null
null
null




 



See this db<>fiddle.

i don't know why my sql throws an error that TRANSLATE is not in-buit function.

The TRANSLATE() was introduced in SQL Server 2017. If you are running an even older version, you should consider upgrading. What version information do you get when you run the command select @@version?
